# Add a paying plan to my website

Tags: node.js, angularjs, online-payment, mean

I have already created a website using [MEAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEAN_(software_bundle)).

Once a user is registered, I want to propose a free trial for 15 days, and a paying plan (eg, $5/month). I want to implement this mechanism, including the paying page.

Does anyone know a fitting payment API that easily integrates with my setup (ie. it is easy to implement in my website)? As I haven't yet decided on a specific payment system/provider, this is secondary at the moment (should have reasonable conditions, though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with `stripe`...